# How to set based row position in table onload in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have saved the table row position in database. Now I want to display the table row according their position. Please tell me how I do this onload of table data in jQuery.

i.e. my code:

```
<table id="table">
<thead>
<th></th>
<th align="left">Title</th>
<th align="left">Importance</th>
<th align="left">Urgency</th>
<th></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%for(Todo todo:todoList){ %>
<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="todocheck" value="<%=todo.getId()%>"/></td>
<td><a href="#" id="aid" style="padding-left:<%=todo.getCss()%>"><%=todo.getTitle() %></a></td>
<td><input type="text" id="importance" value="<%=todo.getImportance()%>" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" id="urgency" value="<%=todo.getUrgency()%>" /> </td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="parentId" id="parentId" value="<%=todo.getParent_tash_id()%>"/></td>

</tr>
<%} %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How does your query look like? You probably will be able to solve the problem there using and `ORDER BY rownr`

Comment: ok i am trying . I am adding order by clause in my query